# WooCommerce external product to new tab

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to have WooCommerce external/affiliate products open in a new tab. This would go for all aspects of a product: image, title, buy now button and archive pages(product category/tags). All I have been able to find is a way to change the "Buy Now" button but no other solutions to the other areas previously mentioned. Other solutions offer a the external link in all the right places(product image, title, buy now button, archive pages), but it can't open in a new tab.

I've tried a bunch of different codes, as mentioned above, all lead to partial solutions. I believe if these can be combined, it may work. But I haven't been successful.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_external_products' );
function redirect_external_products() {
    global $post;
    if ( is_singular( 'product' ) && ! empty( $post ) && ( $product = wc_get_product( $post ) ) && $product->is_type( 'external' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( $product->get_product_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
```

```
function custom_redirect() {
  global $post;
   if( is_single() ){
      $external_link =  get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'external_link', true );
      if($external_link) {  
         echo "<script> window.open(".$external_link.", '_blank') </script>";
         exit;
      }
   }
}
```

I would like all affiliate/external links to open in a new tab. This would include: product image, product title, buy now button, archive page listings(product category/tags).

All previous attempts will only open the Buy Now links in a new tab - but the image and title still direct to the single product page. The first code above from does the trick, but won't open in a new tab. My research tells me that when using the template_redirect function, link targeting is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

remove the previous code and let's add this code in the theme's functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_product_link', 'filter_external_product_permalink', 10, 2 );

if ( ! function_exists( 'filter_external_product_permalink' ) ) {
/**
 * Insert the external url for products in the loop.
 */
function filter_external_product_permalink( $the_permalink, $product ){
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type( 'external' ) ) {
        $external_link =  $product->get_product_url();
        return $external_link;
    }

    return $the_permalink;
}
}


if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open' ) ) {
/**
 * Insert the opening anchor tag for products in the loop.
 */
function woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open() {
    global $product;

    $link = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_product_link', get_the_permalink(), $product );

    $link_target = $product->is_type( 'external' ) ? '_blank' : '_self';

    echo '<a target="' . esc_attr( $link_target ).'" href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">';
}
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'custom_external_add_product_link' , 10, 2 );

if ( ! function_exists( 'custom_external_add_product_link' ) ) {

function custom_external_add_product_link( $permalink ) {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type( 'external' ) ) {

        $permalink = sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>',
            esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
            esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
            esc_attr( $product->id ),
            esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
            esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button product_type_external add_to_cart_button' ),
            esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
        );
    }

    return $permalink;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response...but this doesn't seem to work either.